# Importing module with class method (webapp2.RequestHandler) to check cookie (GAE-Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, cookies, webapp2

I need to check a cookie and use the value to set which template to load.
Below is the working code snippet:

```
import webapp2 as webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os

class genericPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        templatepath = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../templates/'
        ChkCookie = self.request.cookies.get("cookie")
        if ChkCookie == 'default':
            html = template.render(templatepath + 'default_header.html', {})
        else:
            html = template.render(templatepath + 'alt_header.html', {})
    self.response.out.write(html)
```

My question is how to move the `ChkCookie` and if...else statements into a separate module and call it in the code above.  Such as with:

```
# HOW I WANT TO MODIFY THE ABOVE CODE TO SET THE TEMPLATES WITH A COOKIE
import webapp2 as webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os
from testmodule import testlibrary

class genericPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = testlibrary.ChkCookieClass.ChkCookie()
    self.response.out.write(html)
```

I can successfully import the library/module when I keep the `ChkCookie` code in the `genericPage` class and the module only contains a function, like this:

```
# THIS IS THE MODULE I AM IMPORTING
import webapp2 as webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import os

def SkinChk(ChkCookie):
    templatepath = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../templates/'
    if ChkCookie == 'default':
        out = template.render(templatepath + 'default_header.html', {})
    else:
        out = template.render(templatepath + 'alt_header.html', {})
    return out
```

How would I modify the above module code to have the `ChkCookie = self.request.cookies.get("cookie")` in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.get_request to get the request instance in your module.

This is the same as passing self.request to your module.